# Responsive iframe video in portrait mode

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with a vertical video (9:16), wrapped around a div covering the whole remaining screen height. I'm trying to make the iframe cover the whole height of the wrapper and still keep the aspect ratio. The internet is filled with solutions for horizontal video, but I just can't seem to make it work...

The code below kind of works but it feels not so stable. It assumes the width to be 56.25% (9/16) of the height minus the fixed header height. Again, it works but it's a bit jumpy, and breaks when adding margin/padding.

```html
<header>... header stuff ...</header>
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
   <iframe src="..vertical_video..">
</div>
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}
header {height: 60px;width: 100%;background-color: red;}
.iframe-wrapper {height: calc(100vh - 60px);width: 100%;display: flex;justify-content: center;background-color: blue;}
iframe {height: 100%;width: calc((100vh - 60px)*9/16);border:none;}
```